# Failed to install Proc::Daemon on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: perl, installation, cpan, cpanm

I am trying to install [`Proc::Daemon`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Proc-Daemon/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) on Ubuntu 14.10 (Perl v5.20) :

```
$ cpanm Proc::Daemon
--> Working on Proc::Daemon
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AK/AKREAL/Proc-Daemon-0.20.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Proc-Daemon-0.20 ... OK
Building and testing Proc-Daemon-0.20 ... FAIL
! Installing Proc::Daemon failed. See /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1437385026.3674/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

The complete log is here: http://pastebin.com/8s7ndGaC.
The first failed test seems to be:

```
#   Failed test ''kid.pl' daemon is still running'
#   at /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1437385026.3674/Proc-Daemon-0.20/t/02_testmodule.t line 116.
#   Failed test 'stop daemon 'kid.pl''
#   at /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1437385026.3674/Proc-Daemon-0.20/t/02_testmodule.t line 119.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1437385026.3674/Proc-Daemon-0.20/t/02_testmodule.t line 129.
```

The test script `02_testmodule.t` is here: https://api.metacpan.org/source/AKREAL/Proc-Daemon-0.20/t/02_testmodule.t (and here http://pastebin.com/E0n116bA)

Lines 115-119 in the test script:

```
$pid = $daemon->Status( "$cwd/pid_1.file" );
                    ok( $pid == $Kid_PID2, "'kid.pl' daemon is still running" );

                    my $stopped = $daemon->Kill_Daemon();
                    ok( $stopped == 1, "stop daemon 'kid.pl'" );
```

Comment: Looks like this has [already been reported](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=103130) as a bug. (For future reference, metacpan has a link to "Issues" on the sidebar that you should check any time you have a build failure.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks! Do you know how I can add this information to the existing bug history?

Comment: If you don't have a login to rt.cpan.org you should be able to send an email to `bug-Proc-Daemon@rt.cpan.org` with `[rt.cpan.org #103130]` somewhere in the subject line.

Comment: Proc::Daemon version 0.20 builds for me on Ubuntu 14.10 (perl 5.20.1) just using a vanilla `cpan install Proc::Daemon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue was reported](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=103130) and has been resolved in [version 0.21](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::Daemon).